# Straightforward way to import a table from Sql server to postgresql

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, import

I have to import about 50000 rows from a view in sql server into postgresql.

Sql server is 2000 version
Postgresql is 8.X

I thought it was an easy task and I could accomplish it exporting into a csv file.
I'm having lots of trouble and I lost too much time on this task, so I'm looking for an alternative. Is there a well tested way to import data from sql server ? I searched on internet and found some magic migration software but I have a quite simple goal (a single table to import) and I would like to avoid installing untrusted and unknown software. 
Two more possibilities come to my mind: use enterprise manager to connect to Postegresql (with OBCD driver ?) or pgadmin to connect to sql server. Are they both feasible ?

Thanks
Filippo

Comment: It depends on you view data structure too. In my opinion: Using csv is the best way to achieve this copy. Here you can find a good example: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server_to_PostgreSQL_Migration_by_Ian_Harding

Comment: As stated above I'm experiencing lots of problem with csv and I think it is worthless trying to solve all of them. I cannot find a common charset encoding between export and import, I have text fields with an odd number of double quotes, I have text fields longer than 255 char which are truncated during export, import wizard in Pgadmin has misleading error messages, some fields cannot be imported if they are null and so on. In a few word a real nightmare...Maybe they can all be solved in a few minutes, but I'm too scared.